# dead acount gamertag release?

Tags: xbox-network

What I want to know is if there is any way to report a gamertag that is clearly inactive, with no signs of being active again. And if so and the account is closed, can you take that name for yourself when it is?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this. You can't even delete your *own* gamertag.

Microsoft has a help article called [How to delete your Microsoft account and personal information associated with it](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/microsoft-account/delete-information-microsoft-account). It says

> **Note** You cannot delete your gamertag, but if you use an Xbox 360, you can transfer your gamertag to another Microsoft account. This option is not available on Xbox One.

So, assuming you're not on Xbox One, if there's a gamertag you want that is already taken, you would have to find the owner and get them to help you to transfer it to your Microsoft account.